# In MySQL how do I count messages from a user?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have tables as below.

Table **Messages**

```
message_id
parent_id
forum_id
user_id
```

Table **Users**

```
user_id
username
pass
```

How to query a user, and display the count of their messages with their username?

My query:

`select count(subject), user_id from messages group by user_id;`

The problem is that it only displays user_id and count of messages but no username.  How do I make it display the name of the user?

Comment: see my updated answer and let me know if it works or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query you want.

```
$query = "SELECT u.username, COUNT(*) as total_count FROM messages m INNER JOIN users u ON m.user_id = u.user_id GROUP BY U.user_id"
```

Here total_count gives the total count of messages grouped by user id to avoid joining of same usernames.

Comment: thats great!!!, thats actually what am looking for!, perfect.. thank you very much!! am enjoying PHP MYsql now much more.. things works great.. thank you so much for the bother in helping me.. you are brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

You need to join the users table into your query:

```
select count(*), username
from messages, users
where users.user_id = messages.user_id
group by users.user_id;
```

Comment: it should be `select messages.count(*), users.username` & `group by users.user_id;`

Comment: The use of "implicit joining clause" thanks to "where" is deprecated and not so clear... I suppose that Joining the tables in an explicit way is more clear and standard.

Comment: thanks for the answer... but it doesn't work..
i get an error;
Column 'user_id' in group statement is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT username, COUNT(*) FROM messages M
 JOIN users U USING (user_id)
 GROUP BY U.user_id
```

This takes care of a scenario where two different user_id have the same username in the users table. Also this query is MySQL specific and may not work with other RDBMS.

Comment: While you probably can group by `user_id`, it is more conventional to group by the non-aggregate values in the select-list.  Standard SQL and most SQL DBMS would require `username` to appear in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right. But MySQL should allow it. Also I wanted to differentiate between the cases where two different user_id have the same username in the users table.

Comment: WOOOWWW!!!! that works!!!! i think ill have tears in my eyes.. just kidding... wow, MySQL is cool!! thank you very much for the help!! i guess, i have to learn more about PHP MySQL!! thank you again!!

Comment: +1: Good point about distinguishing between two user IDs that happen to have the same name (and would be good as a comment in your answer rather than as a comment after your answer). MySQL lets you get away with stuff that it probably shouldn't let you get away with.  It becomes a question of "are you learning SQL using MySQL for examples", or "are you learning MySQL with no thought that there are other SQL DBMS in existence" - 'you' being the OP.

Comment: the above solution works for me as for now, am still learning.. went from RoR already, and now i want to understand PHP mysql.. is there any other way i could avoid same username? like unique?

Answer (score 0):

Use below. I believe it will work.

```
SELECT messages.user_id, users.username, count(*)
FROM messages, users
WHERE messages.user_id = users.user_id
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: "_When you use count(*) you don't need to use GROUP BY Statement_":  Only in MySQL - maybe.  Any other SQL DBMS will require a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: can you check my query and let me know if it works or not?? I don't have mysql here...

Comment: thanks for that, it did return user_id, username and count. however, it seemed to not displaying other usernames that has same number including counts...

Comment: I don't have a working MySQL to play with (or haven't configured it, would be more accurate).  In the DBMS I do have, there is no chance of it working without the GROUP BY. In MySQL, you would not need to list both ID and name (but, AFAIK, you do need list one or the other), but in other DBMS would need to list all (both) non-aggregate columns (ID _and_ name) in the GROUP BY list.

Comment: i see.. now, i have to move on.. i have lots of things going on my mind.. like I'm building my image gallery from RoR to PHP from scratch.. i need to design my Database well.. if theres only like a function that has 'belongs_to' and 'has_many' to a model.. many thanks again sir jonathan for the bother in helping me..